# How to understand the type of a objective-c block?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

```
- (void)writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:(NSData *)imageData metadata:(NSDictionary *)metadata completionBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryWriteImageCompletionBlock)completionBlock
```

In this function signature, the `completionBlock` has type `ALAssetsLibraryWriteImageCompletionBlock`. However, since when we are creating an anonymous function we use

```
^(int a){
    //code here
}
```

It seems we've never specified anything to be the `type` of a block. So how to understand this unusual type here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the docs for `ALAssetsLibraryWriteImageCompletionBlock` it is defined as:

```
typedef void (^ALAssetsLibraryWriteImageCompletionBlock)(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error);
```

This is a block with no return value that has two parameters.

Your code needs to be something like:

```
[library writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:someData metadata:someMetaData completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
    // completion handler code here with access to assetURL and error
}];
```